# Workflow for an entity based menu system?

Tags: routes, entities

I've been considering stopping to use the menu system all together, in favor of taxonomy terms, or other entities. Entities are superior to regular menu-entries in many ways because they integrate well with most other Core systems as well as contrib.

Since vocabularies already have the ability to create a hierachical structure, taxonomy terms seems to be the ideal candidate here.

The question is, how have you attempted to implement this, and how did it work out? Are there any pitfalls that one should be aware of before trying this, or any limitations that limit the usability of this approach?

Answer (score 2):

I have pretty much abandoned the menu system for most of my sites, or at least the main menu, in favor of [Taxonomy Menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu). Here is a link to my most recent site that takes advantage of Taxonomy Menu

buyagainbaby.com

The main menu there as well as all the blocks you see on the front page are done with taxonomy menu.

The types of sites I design usually categorize some type of product or other information, and it's easy to use views to do some pretty amazing things with taxonomy as arguments, which you cannot do with just the default menu terms or IDs alone.  Take a look at some of my other questions having to do with taxonomy menu, or ask any questions about implementation if you have any.